# Google Map KML output for via destination OR Google Direction API with MKMapkit

Tags: iphone, ios, kml, directions

I tried the apple development sample project
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046

its working fine with the URL too i.e http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=source&daddr=destination&output=kml

but google API not generated the KML output properly if I add to destination in the URL like
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=source&daddr=destination1%20to:destination2&output=kml

it generate the KML only for destination1

while the URL
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=29.94,76.81&daddr=29.97,76.89%20to:30.38,76.77
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=29.94,76.81&daddr=30.38,76.77
show the proper direction

Any Idea how generate the proper KML output

Or any good example for showing path in MKMapkit using Google Direction API

Answer (score 1):

KML from &output=kml is undocumented on Google's side. You should not rely on it. Instead, you can use the [Google Directions Webservice](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) and get JSON or XML that you can parse or transform into KML.

Comment: Apple sample code which I have given link using kml out put check it readme documne it mention use parameter output=kml

Comment: any sample of using Google Direction API